# Merge XMLs based on attributes - change values, add or remove tags

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have a requirement where based on user provided xml, I have to modify my xml and add, remove or modify existing node values. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve it?

Example:
master.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ds>
    <screen id="screenVerification">
        <tasks id="verificationTasks">
            <task id="verificationTask"  server="database">
                <class id="verificationClass" mode="java" value="verificationResults">classA</class>
            </task>

            <task id="verification01Task">
                <class id="verificationClass" mode="java" value="verificationResults">classB</class>
            </task>

            <task id="verification02Task">
                <class id="verificationClass" mode="java" value="verificationResults">classC</class>
            </task>
        </tasks>
    </screen>   
    <screen id="screenMigration">
        <tasks id="migrationTasks">
            <task id="migrationTask">
                <ant id="dbMigrateAnt" mode="ant" value="migrationResults">
                    <file>ops.xml</file>
                    <target>dbMigrate</target>
                </ant>
            </task>
        </tasks>
    </screen>
</ds>
```

user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ds>
        <screen id="screenVerification">
            <tasks id="verificationTasks">
                <task id="verificationTask"  server="database">
                    <class id="verificationClass" mode="java" value="verificationResults">classX</class>
                </task>
                <task id="verification01Task"  server="database">
                    <ant id="dbMigrateAnt" mode="ant" value="migrationResults">
                        <file>a.xml</file>
                        <target>mig</target>
                    </ant>
                </task>
            </tasks>
        </screen>   
        <screen id="screenMigration">
            <tasks id="migrationTasks">
                <task id="migrationTask">
                </task>
                <task id="addedtask">
                    <cmd id="sql" mode="sql">select * from users;</cmd>
                </task>
            </tasks>
        </screen>
    </ds>
```

result.xml
(Need to 
1. replace value of class with id=verificationClass to classX
2. Need to change the task with id=verification01Task
3. Need to remove the task with id=migrationTask
4. Need to add a task with id=addedtask

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ds>
    <screen id="screenVerification">
        <tasks id="verificationTasks">
            <task id="verificationTask"  server="database">
                <class id="verificationClass" mode="java" value="verificationResults">classX</class>
            </task>         
            <task id="verification01Task"  server="database">
                <ant id="dbMigrateAnt" mode="ant" value="migrationResults">
                    <file>a.xml</file>
                    <target>mig</target>
                </ant>
            </task>         
            <task id="verification02Task">
                <class id="verificationClass" mode="java" value="verificationResults">classC</class>
            </task>
        </tasks>
    </screen>   
    <screen id="screenMigration">
        <tasks id="migrationTasks">
            <task id="addedtask">
                <cmd id="sql" mode="sql">select * from users;</cmd>
            </task>
        </tasks>
    </screen>
</ds>
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Programming languagae: java